# Integral of a summation related to $\sin$ expansion

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

I am trying to evaluate the following integral. It has similarity to the Maclaurin expansion for $\sin$.

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\left(2n+x^2\right)!}}\text{dx}$$

- The $\sum$ is convergent for all $x$ using the ratio test.
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}{\sum}=0$
- When $x=1$, the $\sum$ is equal to $\sin(1)$.

Comment: How are you defining $\left(2n+x^2\right)!$ for non integer $x^2$? Are you bringing in the Gamma function?

Comment: Numerically, the integral is approximately $2.25604328958$.

Comment: @robjohn $\Gamma{(2n+x^2+1)}$ I believe

Comment: Inverse Symbolic Calculators do not seem to find anything.

Comment: The only thing I would try before giving up is to represent the reciprocal of the Gamma function using the Hankel contour integral representation [http://www.nbi.dk/~polesen/borel/node14.html], then perform the summation...this way we are left with an integral over $x$ and a contour integral....but one needs a lot of extra luck to make some serious progress on this beast...